# How do I count inside base class?

Tags: c++, oop

I want to improve my skills in C++ and I try to build a code which will store different energy and their consumptions. Everything works, but I don't understand how I can count consumptions. My problem is when I create pointers to the different energies, my d_consumption inside Energy class is reset and I have only the lastest consumption. If possible, I would like to know if my coding style is good.

```
class Energy
{
private:

    double d_totalconsumption = 0.0; //count total consumption
    double d_totalbill        = 0.0; //count total bill $

public:
    Energy(){}
    virtual ~Energy(){}

    void   addConsumption(double d) { d_totalconsumption += d; }
    double totalConsumption() const { return d_totalconsumption; }
    void   addBill(double d)        { d_totalbill += d; }
    double totalBill()        const { return d_totalbill; }

    virtual void   setConsumption(double consumption) =0;
    virtual void   setBill(double billCAD)            =0;
    virtual double getConsumption()             const =0;
    virtual double getBill()                    const =0;

};

class Mazout : public Energy
{
private:

    double d_consumption = 1.e-16; // init to avoid divide by zero later
    double d_bill        = 1.e-16; // init to avoid divide by zero later

public:
    Mazout() : Energy() { }
    virtual ~Mazout(){}

    void   setConsumption(double consumption) { d_consumption = liters; Energy::addConsumption(consumption); }
    void   setBill(double billCAD)            { d_bill = billCAD; }
    double getConsumption()             const { return d_consumption; }
    double getBill()                    const { return d_bill; }

};

class NaturalGas : public Energy
{
private:

    double d_consumption = 1.e-16; //init to avoid divide by zero later
    double d_bill        = 1.e-16; //init to avoid divide by zero later

public:
    NaturalGas() : Energy() {std::cout << std::fixed;}
    virtual ~NaturalGas(){}

    void   setConsumption(double consumption) { d_consumption = consumption; Energy::addConsumption(consumption);  }
    void   setBill(double billCAD)            { d_bill = billCAD; }
    double getConsumption()             const { return d_consumption; }
    double getBill()                    const { return d_bill; }

};


int main()
{

    string input;
    stringstream inputStream;
    int choice;
    bool exit = false;

    Energy *ptrEnergy;
    vector<Energy*> energyList;

    ptrEnergy = new Mazout();

    ptrEnergy->setConsumption(26180);
    ptrEnergy->setBill(26952);

    energyList.push_back(ptrEnergy)

    ptrEnergy = new NaturalGas();

    ptrEnergy->setConsumption(34000);
    ptrEnergy->setBill(17000);

    energyList.push_back(ptrEnergy)




    // print data
    std::cout << "Consumption " << energyList(0)->getConsumption() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bill        " << energyList(0)->getBill()        << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Consumption " << energyList(1)->getConsumption() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bill        " << energyList(1)->getBill()        << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Total Consumption " << ptrEnergy()->getConsumption() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total Bill        " << ptrEnergy()->getBill()        << std::endl;

}
```

I expected something like that.

```
Consumption 26180.0
Bill        26952.0
Consumption 34000.0
Bill        17000.0
Total Consumption 29580.0 // I have 34000.0
Total Bill        43952.0 // I have 17000.0
```

Comment: Outside of that you posted a lot of code. I think you really want to use your debugger to understand what your code is doing. If this is Visual Studio learn what the F9, F10 and F11 keys do and look at your variables while you step through your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If I understand your question correctly, you want to iterate over a vector. Any textbook on C++ will explain this, or you can search for "C++ iterate vector". This code is needlessly complex for this problem; when you learn a new technique, you should implement it in the simplest program possible, a program that does nothing else, and when you post code here you should first remove all unnecessary complication.

Comment: A range based for loop may help with iteration.

Comment: drescherm, I have simplified the code and remove the switch case. I don't know if I have to iterate over a vector. The vector is just here to store my energy. Cannot I cumulative my consumptions of mazout and gas inside the variable d_totalconsumption?

Comment: By the way, I use qtcreator. I think my problem is when I use ptrEnergy = new () I point to another thing and it reset my value inside the Energy class

Comment: To get the total you need to iterate over the objects you have in the vector not just look at the last item you added to the vector.

Comment: To print the individual data you should also iterate over the vector. Instead of always printing the first and second item in the vector without considering there could be more or less than 2 items in the vector.

Comment: ***By the way, I use qtcreator.*** qt-creator is an IDE. Your problems don't depend on the IDE, compiler or even OS choice.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to iterate over the objects. For now, I sum my consumption inside the main and set into total consumption.

Comment: The way you have `d_totalconsumption` in your `Energy` class does not make sense. There are more than one instance of your `Energy` class and they don't share the same total. There is a way to make them share but then all instances have to share which means if you take this an additional step and have customers they can't have individual energy totals.

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept you don't understand is static variable of a class.

Static variables are shared variables across the same class. You refer to them in code with `Classname::variable`. Same idea with static functions.

For example,

```
class A {
public:
    static int object_count;
    int x;
    A(int _x) : x(_x) {
        ++object_count;
    }
};

int A::object_count = 0;

int main(){
    A a1(8);
    cout << A::object_count << endl; // prints 1
    A a2(9);
    cout << A::object_count << endl; // prints 2
}
```

For your particular question, you wish to count the total consumption / cost across all object instances, so you want the counter and functions to be static.

```
class Energy
{
private:

    static double d_totalconsumption = 0.0; //count total consumption
    static double d_totalbill        = 0.0; //count total bill $

public:
    Energy(){}
    virtual ~Energy(){}

    static void   addConsumption(double d) { Energy::d_totalconsumption += d; }
    static double totalConsumption() const { return Energy::d_totalconsumption; }
    static void   addBill(double d)        { Energy::d_totalbill += d; }
    static double totalBill()        const { return Energy::d_totalbill; }

    virtual void   setConsumption(double consumption) =0;
    virtual void   setBill(double billCAD)            =0;
    virtual double getConsumption()             const =0;
    virtual double getBill()                    const =0;

};

// ...

int main()
{
// ...
    std::cout << "Total Consumption " << Energy::totalConsumption() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total Bill        " << Energy::totalBill()        << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniel for the static solution! I will explore this.
drescherjm, I don't really have customers, Energy is linked with another class Building which have energies. I could probably put my `d_totalconsumption` inside `Building` class, but i would like to keep it with the `Energy` class (because it's total consumption of energy). But your point is interesting! Thanks a lot guys

Comment: If you find my solution helpful, instead of posting a "Thank you" answer, please mark my answer as "accepted" and/or upvote.